# how can i add a cursive text in React?

Tags: reactjs, styles

I am planning to have a text in cursive with an approach similar to the function below. how would i do that in place of an underlined line?

```
<Text style={styles.textStyle}>I'm Underline!</Text>

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textStyle: {
    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the following:

```
fontFamily: "cursive"
```